# Merge data into new cell if other cells match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in my workbook that pulls information from another sheet. In column A there are names; A1=Tom, A2=Sarah, A3=Steve, etc.. Column B has dates; B1=July26, B2=August08, B3=July26, etc.

There are 10 rows in my table. What I'm trying to do is compress the information down into a single cell C1, and have it as a single line of text. So for this example: "Tom,Steve: July26,  Sarah: August08"

Right now I've been building an IF statement to compare, but I was wondering if there was a better way; one that doesn't risk a typo mid way that misses something.

This is what I have (I've started from the bottom (row 10) and building up: =IF(B9<>B10,A9&": "&B9&" "&A10&": "&B10,A9&","&A10&": "&B9)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that your process of building from the bottom up is the correct way. Otherwise a single formula would be too complicated, and VBA might be necessary.

To build from the bottom up, this is the formula you need at `C10`. Enter it then copy/paste into `C1:C10`.

```
C10:
=A10 & IF(B10=B11, ",", ": " &TEXT(B10, "mmmmdd") & ". ") & C11
```

p.s. it supposes that your column `B` contains `dates` formatted this way. If they are actually text, then replace `TEXT(B10, "mmmmdd")` with simply `B10`:

```
=A10 & IF(B10=B11,",", ": " & B10 & ". ") & C11
```

[image]